# Zero extending immediate values to fit into the register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

When adding an immediate value into a register, how does the assembler first zero out the register? For example, if I have a register value of:

```
%rax 0x00007fffffffe450
```

And I do:

```
mov $1, %rax
```

It effectively does either:

```
movzbq $1, %rax
```

Or:

```
mov $0x0000000000000001, %rax
```

As it clears out the upper bits to fit into the register. Is this done by the assembler when compiling or the cpu, or where/how does this occur?

---

As a sort of meta question (not directly related to the question above), I do have a bit of a hard time searching for duplicate asm questions as the titles often seem to be very specific. What would be the best way to search for these?

Comment: If we see the former, then the zeroing of the register's upper bits is handled by the CPU executing machine code as part of the definition of `movzbq` at runtime.  If we see the later, then the assembler is generating a long (long) constant as an immediate which will fully fill the register without need for zeroing at runtime.

Comment: `mov $1, %rax` will be encoded as `mov $sign_extended_imm32, r/m64`.  Explicit `mov` to overwriite all 64 bits.  It's definitely not `movzbq`, that's an existing opcode that doesn't have an immediate form.  Try it and use `objdump` to see the disassembly + machine code, and check which `mov` opcode it used.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov.  If you'd written it efficiently as 5-byte `mov $1, %eax`, the upper 32 of RAX would have been overwritten by [implicit zero extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137)

Comment: [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40315803) shows various mov encodings and talks about them in detail.  Maybe not an exact duplicate, but I think that covers the available encodings of `mov` and how the machine works.  Intel's manuals cover the machine-code formats of instructions if you need more than those descriptions.
[How many ways to set a register to zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673696) also shows multiple forms using Intel syntax.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, how do you find the duplicate questions so fast? I try searching on something like "immediate" and that isn't too helpful in a search. It would be nice on StackOverflow if you could store multiple alternate titles for a question (it wouldn't need to be displayed) to help a user find questions more easily.

Comment: Questions like [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) come up frequently as duplicate targets or something I want to link in a comment; my browser autocomplete happens to pop it up as one of the completions when I type "32 upper" in the address bar; sometimes I have to type more or actually hit search if I need to find it again and it's not coming up.

Comment: For the other answers I linked, I had at least a vague recollection of *writing* those answers myself, so I knew basically what to search for. I think I remembered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673696) first as one where I listed multiple mov encodings, then search results while finding that reminded me of the movq vs. movabsq answer I'd written. Also, **knowing the right answer makes it *much* easier to know exactly what to search for even in cases when I don't already remember a specific answers I want to look for.** Then I can search for some key phrases an answer should use.