# Various encodings of mov instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, machine-code

I have the following assembly code for moving immediates into an 8,16,32,64-bit register:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $1, %rax
    mov $2, %eax
    mov $3, %ax
    mov $4, %ah
    mov $5, %al
```

And when debugging in `gdb`:

```
 0x0000000000401000  48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00  ? mov    $0x1,%rax
 0x0000000000401007  b8 02 00 00 00        ? mov    $0x2,%eax
 0x000000000040100c  66 b8 03 00           ? mov    $0x3,%ax
 0x0000000000401010  b4 04                 ? mov    $0x4,%ah
 0x0000000000401012  b0 05                 ? mov    $0x5,%al
```

And on the [intel page](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) it shows:

[image]

Some questions on the **Opcode** column:

- What does the `+rb` or `+rw` or `+rd` mean?
- I'm guessing the `ib`, `iw`, `id`, means immediate-byte, -word, -double- is that correct? What does the `io` in the last row mean?
- What is the `REX` prefix on the `ah` instruction that increments the op code from `b0` to `b4` ?
- Why does the `mov imm, r16` require the `66` prefix? It doesn't list any prefix in the row for `imm16`. It seems the `66` just flags this at a 16bit register?
- Finally, why the three-byte code, `48 c7 c0` for `mov imm, r64`? I don't see

Comment: `48 c7 c0` isn't `mov imm, r64`, it's `mov sign_extended_imm32, r/m64`.  i.e. a REX.W form of the `mov imm32, r/m32` opcode, which you omitted from your image.

Comment: Asking multiple questions in 1 makes it hard to handle for duplicates, but [How does x86 handle byte vs word addressing when executing instructions and reading/writing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58628157) covers the fact that Intel's manuals leave it up to you to know when to use an operand-size prefix depending on what mode you're assembling for (16 or 32/64).  Oh, [Matching the intel codes to disassembly output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63875061) is an almost exact duplicate of that, using the same example as you.

Comment: There is no REX or other prefix on the `b4 04   mov $1, %ah` instruction.  It's just pointing out that mov to AH *can't* be encoded with a REX prefix; that would change the meaning to mov-to-SPL or something like that.

Comment: Ok, I think that list of duplicates covers all your bullet points.