# Breakdown MOV instruction on Intel 64 compatibility mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, mov, instruction-encoding

I'm checking the assembly code for a `MOV` instruction on Intel 64 (long) compatibility sub-mode.

For a `mov edx,408ACB77` the debugger (x32dbg for Windows) shows

```
BA 408ACB77
```

From Intel 64 SDM this MOV instruction in compatibility mode should use a one-byte opcode plus a 32bit immediate value (`77CB8A40`). In Intel SDM the opcode for `MOV` should be `B8 +rd id`. `+rd` means look at the lower three bit of one-byte opcode for the target dword register (i.e. 32 bit register).

From Table 3.1 the `EDX` register has index `0x2` then we get `0x8+0x2 = 0xA`, hence the opcode byte is actually `BA`.

Is the above correct ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, that's why your disassembler / debugger is showing the BA byte separately, and why the total instruction is only 5 bytes long, just opcode + imm32 with no ModRM byte.  For other cases (like 64-bit operand-size with imm32 vs. imm64), see [Various encodings of mov instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64255130) and its duplicate list.  And [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40315803)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks. I've another question about `JMP` `FF25 2892D577`. From Intel SDM I'm not sure if it is of type `FF /4` or `FF /5`. /<digit> should mean that the reg field of following ModR/M byte is actually used as an opcode extension. However for `FF /5` the Op/En `D` entry shows just an Offset/displacement.

Comment: `0x25` in octal is `045`.  The /reg field is `4`.  [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976236) / [x64 instruction encoding and the ModRM byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511482) / https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#ModR.2FM_and_SIB_bytes .  Also [What does the /4 mean in FF /4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24295464)

Comment: Ok, however I don't understand why for `FF /5` the Op/En `D` row says there is just an Offset operand (Operand 1). I would expect a ModR/M byte after the opcode-byte and then the Offset/Displacement.

Comment: FF /5 far indirect `jmp m16:32` doesn't use the D encoding, it uses M because it has a memory operand (like FF25 `FF /4` near indirect which can have a mem or reg source).  The D operand encoding is `EB` or `E9` `jmp rel8` or `jmp rel32`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp  Perhaps there was a bug in an older (or newer?) version of the SDM than Felix last scraped.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Yes, you are right. Coming back to `FF /4` as in `FF25 2892D577` from the JMP reference all `FF /4` combinations use Op/En `M` entry, therefore it seems there is no way to have a displacement/offset operand in the instruction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256147/discussion-between-carlo-c-and-peter-cordes).